# call value of an attribute in a loop with Jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, append

here is my situation,

i have a loop with multiple post, I would like by jquery to add the link previously call in a new div created by js.

It look something like this:

```
 if ($(this).hasClass('64')){

        $(this).append('<a class="video-post-archive" href="">Watch the video</a>');
```

bascially in the above, I add a add a new div, which will contain a href value call from the post.

for this i declare a variable like:

```
        var newlink = $(".widgetizedArea ul li a").attr("href")
```

And then call the value in the append div like:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('64')){

        $(this).append('<a class="video-post-archive" href="">Watch the video</a>');

        $(this).find('a.video-post-archive').attr('href', newlink);

    }
```

The problem im having is that it repeat the same link for all the post from the loop . ..

Example: Item 1 link fins, but item 2 link to item 1 content, item 3 link to item 1 content instead of their own content . . .

Any idea to help me with that ?

It will be brilliant !

Thanks for all :)

--- EDIT ---

In Html, it looks like below ( as we can see it always append the same href unfortunately . . .):

```
<div class="widgetizedArea"><h3>HOW TO...</h3><div class="row"><ul class="large-offset-1 inner-content grid-x grid-margin-x grid-padding-x large-centered medium-centered small-centered">

    <li class="small-3 small-centered medium-3 medium-centered large-3 large-centered colum columns cat-post-item 64 Image" data-permanlink="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/">



                        <a href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/" title="Video post 04">
            <img width="422" height="281" src="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-004.png" class="attachment-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 size-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-004.png 422w, http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-004-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 422px) 100vw, 422px">                </a>

            <a class="post-title" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent link to Video post 04">Video post 04</a>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nisl ut sapien tristique elementum ac eget purus. Nulla porta cursus purus, vitae luctus massa molestie eu. Donec sit amet nibh malesuada, sodales nunc vitae, aliquam lorem. Duis pulvinar leo nisi, nec sodales ex scelerisque ut.</p>


    <a class="video-post-archive" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/"><img src="../wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master-child/assets/img/right-arrow.svg">Watch the video</a></li>


    <li class="small-3 small-centered medium-3 medium-centered large-3 large-centered colum columns cat-post-item 64 Standard" data-permanlink="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-03/">



                        <a href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-03/" title="Video post 03">
            <img width="424" height="283" src="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-003.png" class="attachment-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 size-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-003.png 424w, http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-003-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 424px) 100vw, 424px">                </a>

            <a class="post-title" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-03/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent link to Video post 03">Video post 03</a>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nisl ut sapien tristique elementum ac eget purus. Nulla porta cursus purus, vitae luctus massa molestie eu. Donec sit amet nibh malesuada, sodales nunc vitae, aliquam lorem. Duis pulvinar leo nisi, nec sodales ex scelerisque ut.</p>


    <a class="video-post-archive" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/"><img src="../wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master-child/assets/img/right-arrow.svg">Watch the video</a></li>


    <li class="small-3 small-centered medium-3 medium-centered large-3 large-centered colum columns cat-post-item 64 Video" data-permanlink="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-02/">



                        <a href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-02/" title="Video post 02">
            <img width="422" height="281" src="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-002-1.png" class="attachment-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 size-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-002-1.png 422w, http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-002-1-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 422px) 100vw, 422px">                </a>

            <a class="post-title" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-02/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent link to Video post 02">Video post 02</a>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nisl ut sapien tristique elementum ac eget purus. Nulla porta cursus purus, vitae luctus massa molestie eu. Donec sit amet nibh malesuada, sodales nunc vitae, aliquam lorem. Duis pulvinar leo nisi, nec sodales ex scelerisque ut.</p>


    <a class="video-post-archive" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/"><img src="../wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master-child/assets/img/right-arrow.svg">Watch the video</a></li>


    <li class="small-3 small-centered medium-3 medium-centered large-3 large-centered colum columns cat-post-item 64 Video" data-permanlink="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-01/">



                        <a href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-01/" title="Video post 01">
            <img width="422" height="281" src="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-001-1.png" class="attachment-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 size-cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-10 wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-001-1.png 422w, http://thelocalsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/blog-001-1-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 422px) 100vw, 422px">                </a>

            <a class="post-title" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-01/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent link to Video post 01">Video post 01</a>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id nisl ut sapien tristique elementum ac eget purus. Nulla porta cursus purus, vitae luctus massa molestie eu. Donec sit amet nibh malesuada, sodales nunc vitae, aliquam lorem. Duis pulvinar leo nisi, nec sodales ex scelerisque ut.</p>


    <a class="video-post-archive" href="http://thelocalsite.local/video-post-04/"><img src="../wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master-child/assets/img/right-arrow.svg">Watch the video</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `var newlink = $(".widgetizedArea ul li a").attr("href")` will always be the href of the first found element. I think, that's your issue, but it's hard to say without understanding, how does `.widgetizedArea` look like.

Comment: Hi ALex,

Thanks for answering. I have edit the post and added the html if that helps ??

Thanks a lot :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem is you always capturing the first links with

```
$(".widgetizedArea ul li a").attr('href')
```

You should do instead

```
$(".widgetizedArea li.64").each(function(){
   var $ele = $(this);
   var link = $ele.find('a').attr("href");
   $ele.append('<a class="video-post-archive" href="' + link + '">Watch the video</a>')
});
```

This will solve your problem, let me know if you need any further help.
Enjoy :)

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much ! May i know why using a variable ele and not this directly ? what dos make the difference ? Thanks for all :)

Comment: Don't need to convert this into jQuery object twice :)

Comment: To save some time (fraction of it), you can call it good practice if there are more than one uses of the `this`